# How to prevent search bar in start menu of Windows 10 to search the web?

Tags: window, start-menu, windows-search, windows-10-preview

By default, `Windows 10` performs search in my programs, my folders, settings and Web. How I can customise these? I don't want to use Web. It consume my internet traffic, and it is a reason for the delay.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [How To Remove/Disable Web Search From Windows 10](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/remove-disable-web-search-from-windows-10/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Block/Remove "Web"/Bing Search from Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/832412/block-remove-web-bing-search-from-windows-10)

Comment: @DavidPostill, it is weird, but this advice does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This solution](https://superuser.com/a/923206/274614) works for me.

1. Open Advanced Firewall panel -> Outbound
2. Find two entries named "Search"
3. Open their properties and change "Allow connection" to "Block connection"

Answer (score 0):

Start a search by start typing in start menu. On the left you'll see some icons. CLick the configuration icon. You will be able to customize the search and disable web search as well.